# Railo/pd4ml: HTML comments inside TDs are printed

Tags: java, html, pdf-generation, railo

I'm using Railo (pd4ml) with cf_document to print a PDF file, generated from a HTML. However, say I have the following snippet:

```
<td>
<!-- Foo -->
Bar
</td>
```

The exported cell says "Foo Bar" in the PDF. Of course, "Foo" shouldn't appear, since it's a comment. This doesn't happen with comments in other elements.

Modifying the HTML is not my favorite choice, since we have many HTMLs and we also use them as normal pages with i18n so it helps our designer to see where he is.

Besides modifying the HTML and moving or deleting the comments, does anyone know about a solution for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is occurring, you need to open a bug ticket: http://issues.jboss.org/browse/RAILO

Comment: I ended up moving the comments to my server-side language comments instead of HTML. But thank you very much for your suggestion (and for being the only answer :P ). As soon as I have some time I'll try to reproduce and file a bug with more detail.